# Javascript RegExp Matching weirdness

Tags: javascript

I have a `RegExp`:

`/.?(NCAA|Division|I|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?/gi`

and some text `"Champion"`

somehow, this is coming back as a match, am I crazy?

```
0: "pio"
1: "i"
index: 4
input: "Champion"
length: 2
```

the loop is here:

```
// contruct the pattern, dynamically
var someText = "Champion";
var phrase = ".?(NCAA|Division|I|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?";
var pat = new RegExp(phrase, "gi"); // <- ends up being 
var result;

while( result = pat.exec(someText) ) {
     // do stuff!   
}
```

There has to be something wrong with my RegExp, right?

EDIT:
The `.?` thing was just a quick and dirty attempt to say that I'd like to match one of those words AND/OR one of those words with a single char on either side. ex:

```
\sNCAA\s
NCAA
NCAA\s
\sNCAA
```

GOAL:
I'm trying to do some simple hit highlighting based on some search words. I've got a function that gets all of the text nodes on a page, and I'd like to go through them all and highlight any matches to any of the terms in my `phrase` variable.

I think that I just need to rework how I am building my RegExp.

Comment: Is `pat` a RexExp object, or a string? In your code, it's a string.

Comment: @Matt It's actually a RegExp, let me fix the code... I thought it works both ways, no?

Comment: You never really specified what you WANT to happen or what you EXPECT to happen here.  Now it's not quite so obvious.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "it works both ways." It might be helpful if you could explain a little more about the end goal you're trying to accomplish, because this might be something better done with `String.split()`.

Comment: let me update the question with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: perhaps it would be best to mark this question as resolved and create a new question addressing the entirety of the issue, i.e. creating a proper mechanism for doing the hit highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Champion` matches `/.?I.?/i`.

Your own output notes that it's matching the substring "pio".

Perhaps you meant to bound the expression to the start and end of the input, with `^` and `$` respectively:

```
/^.?(NCAA|Division|I|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?$/gi
```

I know you said to ignore the `.?`, but I can't: it's most likely wrong, and it's most likely going to continue to cause you problems. Explain why they're there and we can tell you how to do it properly. :)

Comment: @samandmoore: You didn't even mention `.?` in your update, let along explain the use of them.

Comment: it's updated with that info, I didn't save it right away, my bad.

Comment: @samandmoore: If you're trying to allow whitespace either side, prefer trimming this whitespace from the input string beforehand.

Comment: @Tomalak That won't work exactly though because I'd like to find the matches without tampering with the input string. What the goal states is that I'm trying to take some text and highlight a match in it. I'd like to allow it to be lenient by one char on either side, even if that turns up a false positive.

Comment: @samandmoore: Then, according to that logic, "Champion" matching is _completely_ reasonable according to your use case.

Comment: I really think you need to better define which inputs will be accepted, and which will not. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Add start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to the regexp.

```
/^.?(NCAA|Division|I|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?$/gi
```

Without the anchors, the regexp's match can start and end anywhere in the string, which is why

```
/.?(NCAA|Division|I|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?/gi.exec('Champion')
```

can match `pio` and `i`: because it's *actually* matching around the (case-insensitive) `I`. If you leave the anchors off, but remove the `...|I|...`, the regex won't match `'Champion'`:

```
> /.?(NCAA|Division|Basketball|Champions,|1939-2011).?/gi.exec('Champion')
null
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you're specifying case-insensitivity, and secondly, you are matching the letter `I` as one of your matchable string.

`Champion` would match `pio` and `i`, because they both match `/.?I.?/gi`

It however doesn't match `/.?Champions,.?/gi` because of the trailing comma.